# Configure eclipse to insert pydoc compatible comments on class, functions and modules

Tags: python, eclipse

Is there a way to configure eclipse such that it inserts PyDoc compatible comments. Currently <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> are set to add comments on a python file in eclipse but they are not PyDoc compatible. I am looking for a function (and preferably a key-binding) that will allow to insert Comments/strings when creating new functions, classes and modules. (Sorry for a pedestrian question, I am new to eclipse).